# Getting the current user_id and storing it

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, controller

I want to store the User_id in my table commande but it doesn't work with what i did.

This is the var dump of my page validation.html.twig as you can see user:null

```
Commandes {#745 ▼
  -id: 29
  -user: null
  -confirm: 0
  -date: DateTime {#742 ▶}
  -reference: 0
  -commande: array:6 [▶]

...
}
...
public function prepareCommandeAction()
    {
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if (!$session->has('commande'))
            $commande = new Commandes();
        else
            $commande = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Commandes')->find($session->get('commande'));

        $commande->setDate(new \DateTime());
        $commande->setUser($this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser());
        $commande->setConfirm(0);
        $commande->setReference(0);
        $commande->setCommande($this->bill());

        if (!$session->has('commande')) {
            $em->persist($commande);
            $session->set('commande',$commande);
        }

        $em->flush();

        return new Response($commande->getId());
    }
```

[image]

### This is the mapping :

commandes.php

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="commandes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User  $user
 * @return Commandes
 */
public function setUser(\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $User = null)
{
    $this->User = $User;
    return $this;

}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
```

---

user.php

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->commandes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->address = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $commandes;

    /**
     * Add commandes
     *
     * @param \FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes
     */
    public function addCommandes(\FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes)
    {
        $this->commandes[] = $commandes;
    }

    /**
     * Remove commandes
     *
     * @param \FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes
     */
    public function removeCommande(\FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes)
    {
        $this->commandes->removeElement($commandes);
    }



    /**
     * Get commandes
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCommandes()
    {
        return $this->commandes;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried just using the controller method `Controller::getUser()`? And have you got the relationship setup on the entity? can we see the mapping code?

Comment: right now i will put the mapping in my post on top. but when i'm doing schema validate , the mapping is good

Comment: @DevDonkey did you see the mapping code ?

Comment: are you sure you want **many** users to **one** commande? (sorry Im not sure what commande is).  It feels like that maybe the wrong way around.

Comment: yes i want many users , because command is order. when a user add a product he can validate is order ->[commande] and every order must have a user_id

Comment: ok, but youre getters/setters/adders appear to be reversed. you should have addUser, not setUser, and setcommand, not addCommand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102387/discussion-between-sirius-and-devdonkey).

Comment: @DevDonkey Sorry for the delayed response. I just noticed now that i did pasted the wrong getters/setters for [commandes.php]. I edited my post on top now there is the getters/setters for user. I don't think so the problem come from the relationship between user.php and commandes, i'm sure there is something wrong in my controller but i don't see the mistake that i made.

Comment: @DevDonkey i fount the error it was in my getters/setters of my user id in my Commandes.php . This is how it should be:  `/**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Commandes
     */
    public function setUser(\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;

    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }`